# how to find junk value or unmatched value in a column when validating same tables in two different database (source to target) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

for example i have two tables,student in source and student1 in target. 
student and student1 having columns sname,m,p,c ( sname as student name,and m,p,c as subject marks.i need to find out the column name and the value where '&*' is present.

student [image] 
and 
student1 [image]

the output should be like [image]

Comment: by junk, do you simply mean any non-digit?  Or do you mean any value (even a number) in target that is different than source for a given sname?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `NATURAL JOIN` to join two tables with the same names of the columns. A query with natural join will get you all the records that match. Then,  you can substract those results from query returning records from the `student1` table and you'll have records that were left out by the natural join (meaning, the records having junk values):

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  sname VARCHAR2(20),
  m VARCHAR2(20),
  p VARCHAR2(20),
  c VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE student1 (
  sname VARCHAR2(20),
  m VARCHAR2(20),
  p VARCHAR2(20),
  c VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES ('rama', '50', '60', '70');
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('laxman', '70', '50', '60');
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('sita', '60', '70', '50');
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('kalpu', '40', '80', '70');
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('some student', '*', '80', '70');

INSERT INTO student1 VALUES ('rama', '50', '60', '70');
INSERT INTO student1 VALUES ('laxman', '70', '&*', '60');
INSERT INTO student1 VALUES ('sita', '60', '70', '50');
INSERT INTO student1 VALUES ('kalpu', '40', '80', '70');
INSERT INTO student1 VALUES ('some student', '40', '80', '70');

COMMIT;

SELECT
    *
  FROM student1

MINUS

SELECT
    *
  FROM student s
    NATURAL JOIN student1 s1
;
```

Output:

```
SNAME                M                    P                    C                  
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
laxman               70                   &*                   60
```

Comment: but if i have 1000 of column how to specifically i can know where is the junk?

Comment: @KalpataruMAhanta You would have to use `DBMS_SQL` to loop through all the records returned by the query I proposed and all the columns and check each of columns for having a value that is not a number. By the way, how do you define a junk value? Is it "not a number"? Or can there be other values you would consider a junk? Or "junk" values are any values (even numerical) that are different than in the `student` table in repspective columns?

Comment: can we compare each columns source to target after filtering the unmatched rows by joining  like show student1.column_name when student.column_name<> student1.column_name or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can take full outer join on all the columns and add where clause where we check for columns with null value.

For example:

select * from A
FULL OUTER JOIN
B on A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col2 = B.col2...
Where A.col1 IS NULL OR B.col1 is NULL or A.col2 IS NULL or B.col2 is null ....